# VBA Issue: How can I change the value to "X" to "Y" in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, first I would like to check if the value inside the cell that comes under the `Range (E2:E40)` has the value "X" and if that particular cell has that value, then the value inside that cell should be changed to "Y". Is there any way to mention like this using VBA?

I would like to create a macro so that in the report, if we see the value "X" in the range E2-E40, then the value should change to "Y".

I have tried to use this command, but I got an error message:

```
If Range("E2:E40").Value = "X" Then Range("E2:E40").Value = "Y"
```

I tried to run the code that was mentioned below, but I got an error message: 
`Run time error '13': Type Mismatch`

Comment: you would either need to use something like `application.match()`, `.find()`, or loop with `InStr` through values to determine if "X" is within the range.  You can change the entire range to read one output, just like your written `.value = "Y"`

Comment: You can't check an entire range like that.  If you want to know if *every* cell in that range is "X", you can use `COUNTIF()`. Otherwise, you will need to loop through each cell and check its value.

Comment: `[Worksheet].Range("more than a single cell).Value` is a 2D variant array, not a scalar intrinsic data type; you can't assign to an array like that - that's why there's a "type mismatch".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through each cell in the range. Change the worksheet name as required.

```
For Each cel In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E40")
    If cel.Value = "X" Then cel.Value = "Y"
Next cel
```

Comment: Hi GMalc,
I copied the code, but the value didnt change at all. I will check one more time.

Comment: Since I don't know the workbook and worksheet names you are using, You should always identify the workbook and worksheet you are working on.  I used `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`, you can use `Workbooks("your workbook name").Sheets("your sheet name")`.  `ThisWorkbook` refers to the macro enabled workbook that contains the vba code you are executing.

Answer (score 7):

Use Replace:

```
Range("E2:E40").Replace "X","Y",XlWhole
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, I tried to use this code, but I got an error message:
Compile error: Expected : =

Comment: @jjm see edit, I should know better.  the `()` are not needed.